# How to call an object something other than the name of its class when referencing it with another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am generating scaffolding for 2 classes in Rails 4 - `Room` and `Player`.

Generally speaking, in terms of relationship:

- `Player belongs_to Room`
- `Room has_many Players`

Meaning that when a player is in a room, they will reference it.

However, Players can also create Rooms - so a Room will have an owner. When I call `room.owner` - I would like it to reference this. However, I am not sure how to set something like this up. **How can I make a property like `owner` reference a `Player` object while still maintaining a list of other players inside of a `players` property?**

Here is what I have run so far:

`rails generate scaffold Room name:string owner:integer`

`rails generate scaffold Player name:string room_id:integer`

**example**

Ideally I would like to be able to do:

```
room = Room.find(room_id)
room.owner.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the scaffold room to this:

```
rails generate scaffold Room name:string owner_id:integer
```

and change the app/models/room.rb:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner , :class_name => 'Player'
  has_many :players
  #your code
end
```

then you can use the reference, remember set up the owner_id when creating the room.

Comment: Thank you. Today I learned you can do this: `:class_name => 'Player'`!